# Recyclerview with separator, material scroller and letters

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a Recyclerview that looks like this (taken from Telegram contacts list) [image]

It should have

1. Letters
2. Material scroller with letters
3. Separator between different letters

It should load names from a txt file in the assets folder and images from the drawable folder.
Right now I'm using a simple list view with images and names, but how can I implement these features with a recyclerview?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1 and 2 you can use this [Library](https://github.com/yeahia2508/Android-Material-Fast-Scroll-Demo) and for the 3rd you can use following code in List item.

```
 <View  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="2dp"
android:background="#c0c0c0"/>
```